# Signal handler accepts (*args), how do I provide them?

Tags: python, signal-handling

I'm using a library called BACpypes to communicate over network with a PLC.  The short version here is that I need to start a BACpypes application in its own thread and then perform read/write to the plc in this separate thread.

For multiple PLC's, there is a processing loop that creates an application (providing the plc ip address), performs read writes on plc using application, kills application by calling BACpypes **stop(*args)** from the Core module, calls join on the thread, and then moves on to next ip address in the list until we start over again. This works for as many ip addresses (PLCs) as we have, but as soon as we are back at the first ip address (PLC) again, I get the error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Here is the short code for my thread class, which uses the stop() and run() functions from BACpypes core.

```
class BACpypeThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        Thread.name = name
    def run(self):
        run()
    def stop(self):
        stop()
```

It seems like I'm not correctly killing the application.  So, I know stop(*args) is registered as a signal handler according to BACpypes docs. Here is a snippet I pulled from this link http://bacpypes.sourceforge.net/modules/core.html

```
core.stop(*args)
Parameters: args – optional signal handler arguments
This function is called to stop a BACpypes application. It resets the running boolean value. This function also installed as a signal handler responding to the TERM signal so you can stop a background (deamon) process:

$ kill -TERM 12345
```

I feel like I need to provide a kill -term signal to make the ip address available again.  I don't know how to do that.  Here's my question...

1) In this example, 12345 is the process number I believe.  How do I figure out that number for my thread?

2) Once I have the number, how do I actually pass the kill -TERM signal to the stop function?  I just don't know how to actually write this line of code. So if someone could explain this that would be great.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Before stopping the core, you need to free the socket.

I use :

```
    try:
        self.this_application.mux.directPort.handle_close()
    except:
        self.this_application.mux.broadcastPort.handle_close()
```

After that I call stop
then `thread.join()`